# linux how to add a file to a specific folder within a zip file

Tags: linux, zip

i know how to add a file to the root folder within a zip file:

> zip -g xxx.apk yyy.txt

but i've no idea how to specify a particular folder within a zip file

Answer (score 39, accepted):

If you need to add the file to the same folder as in the original directory hierarchy, then you just need to add the full path to it:

```
zip -g xxx.zip folder/file
```

Otherwise, probably the easiest way to do that is to create the same layout you need in the zip file in a temporary directory.

Comment: if i wanna put yyy.txt into xxx.apk's assests' folder, firstly i must creat assests folder,then move yyy.txt into it. And then excute zip -g xxx.apk assests/yyy.txt

Comment: If you want to have the good hierarchy without copying files into a newly created dir, you can create a symbolic link : ln -s long_path_on_disk folder_in_zip. Then, zip -g xxx.zip folder_in_zip/file

Answer (score 11):

To elaborate on @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams answer from a year ago, you can use a lower level library, such as the one that comes with Python:

```
#!/bin/bash
python -c '
import zipfile as zf, sys
z=zf.ZipFile(sys.argv[1], "a")
z.write(sys.argv[2], sys.argv[3])
z.close()
' myfile.zip source/dir/file.txt dir/in/zip/file.txt
```

This will open `myfile.zip` and add `source/dir/file.txt` from the file system as `dir/in/zip/file.txt` in the zip file.

Answer (score 4):

Info-ZIP cannot do this. You will need to write a script or program in a language that has lower-level access to zip files.

Comment: if i wanna put yyy.txt into xxx.apk's assests' folder, firstly i must creat assests folder,then move yyy.txt into it. And then excute zip -g xxx.apk assests/yyy.txt

Comment: Or you can generate an artificial zip entry that puts it in `assets/`, then combine it with the data from the file and add it to the zip file.

Answer (score 3):

I have expended a little @"that other guy" solution

Go to console, press ctrl+x,ctrl+e, paste there

```
( cat <<-'EOF'
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# -lt 3 ]; then
echo my_zip.zip your/existing/file_to_add.xml directory_in_zip/file_to_add.xml
exit
fi

python -c '
import zipfile as zf, sys
z=zf.ZipFile(sys.argv[1], "a")
z.write(sys.argv[2], sys.argv[3])
z.close()' $1 $2 $3
EOF
) > /tmp/zip-extend && chmod +x /tmp/zip-extend
```

then run `/tmp/zip-extend my_zip.zip your/existing/file_to_add.xml directory_in_zip/file_to_add.xml`

Example:

```
cd /tmp
touch first_file.txt
zip my_zip.zip first_file.txt
unzip -l my_zip.zip
mkdir -p your/existing
touch your/existing/file_to_add.xml
/tmp/zip-extend my_zip.zip your/existing/file_to_add.xml directory_in_zip/file_to_add.xml
unzip -l my_zip.zip
cd -
```

Result:

```
Archive:  my_zip.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
        0  2013-12-17 15:24   first_file.txt
        0  2013-12-17 15:24   directory_in_zip/file_to_add.xml
---------                     -------
        0                     2 files
```