# How can I add files to a Jar file?

Tags: java, jar

I want to add a series of files previously extracted from other files(already done) to a jar. These files will be overwriting files inside the JAR. What is the most efficient way to do it?
I need it to be fast.
Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A JAR file is a ZIP file, remember.

Just use some ZIP library.

Comment: If you just want to throw some files in every now and then what I do on Windows 8.1 is rename the extension of the file from jar to zip. Then I can just use Windows Explorer to navigate into the file and add/delete as necessary. Set it back to jar when you're done and get yourself a beer.

Answer (score 28):

```
jar -uf my.jar file1 file2...
jar -uf my.jar dir/
```

or mixed

```
jar -uf my.jar file dir/
```

Comment: I don't know why is this so under-voted answer. When I tried to use `jar -u` in bash script I had to press `Ctrl + C` for the script to continue (for some inexplicable reason). adding `-f` fixed it.

Answer (score 21):

```
jar -u file.jar file1 file2 file3 ...
```

Comment: JAR is nothing more than ZIP, so - 

zip -ur file.zip dir-fith-files/

Comment: it works for linux / mac os / windows, but you need to install it for your OS.

Comment: if it needs to be installed, people are oing to complain.

Comment: why do you want your customers to add something into JAR file? Let them specify the folder with files and read them if you need.

Comment: @zyngawow, if whoever is meant to use this can't handle the command line, they should be able to use whichever zip application they prefer. I'd suspect that if non-tech users are meant to fiddle with settings stored within jar/zip file in any way (CLI or GUI), they're going to complain anyway.

Comment: Some people told me to instead of unzip all the files, add them directly to the jar. How could I do this?
It is a minecraft launcher that downloads modpacks(completely legal), so there is a need to modify the game

Comment: @zyngawow **You** can just do it with the method explained above. Why do other people have to repeat it?

Comment: How can I do this just with Java?I dont want any more downloads

Comment: I needed to use the '-f' flag to get this to work (see @Jonathan L's answer)

Answer (score 7):

Just to add to the existing answers, there is at least one special case: so-called executable JAR files. If you add another JAR file as a dependency -- whether you use jar or zip -- it will complain that the embedded file is compressed:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to open nested entry 'BOOT-INF/lib/file.jar'. It has been compressed and nested jar files must be stored without compression. Please check the mechanism used to create your executable jar file
```

The solution to this is to use the `0` option to jar:

```
jar uvf0 myfile.jar BOOT-INF/lib/file.jar
```

You don't need this for normal class files.

Answer (score 4):

```
//Add a file in jar in a particular folder
jar uvf <jar file name> <file to be added> <folder name inside jar>
```

Comment: how do I add file to the root of the jar file - what to use for a `<folder name inside jar>`. My use case is `src/config.properties`. I tried `jar --update --file=../demo.jar --main-class=demo.App src/config.properties <???>`.

Answer (score 3):

```
 zip file.jar file1 file2 file3
```

works for me in Mac Os 10.7.5

Answer (score 1):

Extending the existing answers, I find the **`-C`** *jar* option very useful when adding files that are on their own folder and you flatten their path out.

```
$ jar uf jar-file -C /path/to/my_jars/ this_useful.jar
```

---

You will end up having this_useful.jar right in the JAR's root:

```
$ jar tf jar-file | grep this_useful.jar
this_useful.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

If someone needs a programmatically answer, here it is.

```
private static void createJar(File source, JarOutputStream target) {
    createJar(source, source, target);
}

private static void createJar(File source, File baseDir, JarOutputStream target) {
    BufferedInputStream in = null;

    try {
        if (!source.exists()) {
            throw new IOException("Source directory is empty");
        }
        if (source.isDirectory()) {
            // For Jar entries, all path separates should be '/'(OS independent)
            String name = source.getPath().replace("\\", "/");
            if (!name.isEmpty()) {
                if (!name.endsWith("/")) {
                    name += "/";
                }
                JarEntry entry = new JarEntry(name);
                entry.setTime(source.lastModified());
                target.putNextEntry(entry);
                target.closeEntry();
            }
            for (File nestedFile: source.listFiles()) {
                createJar(nestedFile, baseDir, target);
            }
            return;
        }

        String entryName = baseDir.toPath().relativize(source.toPath()).toFile().getPath().replace("\\", "/");
        JarEntry entry = new JarEntry(entryName);
        entry.setTime(source.lastModified());
        target.putNextEntry(entry); in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(source));

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        while (true) {
            int count = in .read(buffer);
            if (count == -1)
                break;
            target.write(buffer, 0, count);
        }
        target.closeEntry();
    } catch (Exception ignored) {

    } finally {
        if ( in != null) {
            try { in .close();
            } catch (Exception ignored) {
                throw new RuntimeException(ignored);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another example of copying directory content to JAR file.

```
/**
 * Copy source directory to a folder inside JAR file.
 * @param directory
 * @param jarFile
 * @param jarFolder
 * @throws Exception
 */
protected void copyDirectoryToJar(String directory, String jarFile, String jarFolder)
        throws Exception {
    
    // Initialize local variables.
    FileSystem destinationJarFileSystem = null;
    Exception exception = null;
    try {
        // Get source path.
        final Path sourcePath = Paths.get(directory);
        
        // Get destination JAR file system and destination path inside the JAR file.
        final URI uri = URI.create("jar:file:/" + jarFile.replace(File.separatorChar, '/'));
        final Map<String, String> environment = Map.of("create", "true");
        destinationJarFileSystem = FileSystems.newFileSystem(uri, environment);
        final Path destinationPath = destinationJarFileSystem.getPath(jarFolder);

        // Copy source directory into target JAR file.
        copyFromDirToJar(sourcePath, destinationPath, destinationJarFileSystem);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        exception = e;
    }
    finally {
        // Close JAR file systems.
        try {
            if (destinationJarFileSystem != null) {
                destinationJarFileSystem.close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            if (exception == null) {
                exception = e;
            }
        }
    }
    
    // Throw exception.
    if (exception != null) {
        throw exception;
    }   
}

/* Recursively copy the source sub directories and files to target JAR file system.
 * @param sourcePath
 * @param destinationPath
 * @param destinationFileSystem
 */
private static void copyFromDirToJar(Path sourcePath, Path destinationPath, FileSystem destinationFileSystem)
        throws Exception {
    
    // Create destination directory if it doesn't exist.
    if (!Files.exists(destinationPath)) {
        Files.createDirectories(destinationPath);
    }
    
    // If the source and destination paths designate files, copy the source
    // file directly to the destination file.
    if (Files.isRegularFile(sourcePath) && Files.isRegularFile(destinationPath)) {
        Files.copy(sourcePath, destinationPath, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
    }
    
    // List sub directories in the source path.
    Exception [] exception = new Exception [] {null};
    Files.list(sourcePath).forEachOrdered(sourceSubPath -> {
        try {
            Path fileOrFolder = sourceSubPath.getFileName();
            Path destinationSubPath = destinationFileSystem.getPath(destinationPath.toString(), fileOrFolder.toString());
            
            // Copy sub directories recursively or copy a single file.
            if (Files.isDirectory(sourceSubPath)) {
                copyFromDirToJar(sourceSubPath, destinationSubPath, destinationFileSystem);
            }
            else {
                Files.copy(sourceSubPath, destinationSubPath, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            exception[0] = e;
        }
    });
    
    // Throw exception.
    if (exception[0] != null) {
        throw exception[0];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're wondering "how can I add a file at /host/path/file.txt to /jar/path/newfilename.txt", then unfortunately the answer is that you can't. You can only create the directory structure and filenames on the host that you want to be in the jar file. As other answers mentioned, the jar is just a zip archive, so you could use a zip command to add the files instead, but the same restrictions seem to apply. See related questions for zips: [linux how to add a file to a specific folder within a zip file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9289734/linux-how-to-add-a-file-to-a-specific-folder-within-a-zip-file) and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/621321/add-file-in-a-sub-directory-of-a-zip

Here you can see some of the behavior for adding a file to a JAR

```
~ ls
HelloWorld.class HelloWorld.java
~ jar cf HelloWorld.jar HelloWorld.class
~ jar tf HelloWorld.jar
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
HelloWorld.class
~ mkdir -p path/on/host
~ touch path/on/host/newfile.txt
~ jar uf HelloWorld.jar path/on/host/
~ jar tf HelloWorld.jar
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
HelloWorld.class
path/on/host/
path/on/host/newfile.txt
~ mkdir -p otherpath/on/host
~ touch otherpath/on/host/otherfile.txt
~ jar uf HelloWorld.jar -C otherpath/on/host/ ./
~ jar tf HelloWorld.jar
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
HelloWorld.class
path/on/host/
path/on/host/newfile.txt
otherfile.txt
```

The `-C` flag seems to act identically to just CDing into a directory prior to running `jar uf`. It *doesn't* allow copying to a different path in the jar than on the host

Here's a small script to create the target directory structure for the JAR in a tmp directory and then copy it over:

```
# copyToJarAtPath.sh
# usage: ./copyToJarAtPath.sh <path to jar> <source path> <target path in jar>
set -x
set -e
echo "jar: '$1', host path: '$2', target path: '$3'"
tmpd=$(mktemp -d)
echo "temp dir: $tmpd"
mkdir -p "$tmpd/$(dirname "$3")"
cp -R $2 "$tmpd/$3"
jar uf $1 -C $tmpd $3
```

This will work for individual files or for directories. Not sure about paths with spaces though, so that might require some tweaking.
Example usage (script echo output trimmed):

```
# single file

~ ./copyToJarAtPath.sh HelloWorld.jar path/on/host/newfile.txt a/b/c.txt
~ jar tf HelloWorld.jar
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
HelloWorld.class
path/on/host/
path/on/host/newfile.txt
a/b/c.txt

# directory 

~ mkdir -p foo/bar/baz
~ touch foo/bar/baz/image.png
~ ./copyToJarAtPath.sh HelloWorld.jar foo/bar/baz new/img/path
~ jar tf HelloWorld.jar
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
HelloWorld.class
path/on/host/
path/on/host/newfile.txt
a/b/c.txt
new/img/path/
new/img/path/image.png
```

Answer (score -1):

```java
String cmd = "jar uvf " + "jarName" + " " + "Filename";
System.out.println(cmd);
try {
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
}
catch (Exception ex) {
}
```