# Python output not displayed in jar file

Tags: java, python

I have created a java gui which takes values from the user send it to python file for processing and then displays the output from the python file onto the java gui. This is working perfectly on eclipse but when i exported it into a jar file the output is not displayed. I've seen a bunch of other questions like this but they do not give a solution that would help me.

This is how i connect my python script to java.

```
public void connection(String name)
{
 ProcessBuilder pb= new ProcessBuilder("python","recomold.py","--movie_name",name);
  ///System.out.println("running file");
  Process process = null;
 try {
  process = pb.start();
 } catch (IOException e1) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e1.printStackTrace();
 }
  int err = 0;
 try {
  err = process.waitFor();
 } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e1.printStackTrace();
 }
 // System.out.println("any errors?"+(err==0 ? "no" : "yes"));
 /* try {
  System.out.println("python output "+ output(process.getInputStream()));
 } catch (IOException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
 }*/
  try {
  matches.setText(output(process.getInputStream()));
 } catch (IOException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
 }
}

private String output(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
 BufferedReader br = null;
 try{
  br= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
  String line = null;
  while((line=br.readLine())!=null)
  {
   sb.append(line+"\n");
   //descp.setText("<html><br/><html>");
   //sb.append("\n");
  }
 }
 finally
 {     
   br.close();     
 }
 return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Your Python script is likely not included into your Jar. Have you tried including manually as suggested in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12239764/how-can-i-add-files-to-a-jar-file ?

Comment: im not able to follow that since im using windows

Comment: I see. Temporarily changing the name of your archive to .zip might do the trick. Then you can try to open it with your regular archiver ?