# Python output not displayed in jar file when run

Tags: java, python

I have created a java gui which takes values from the user send it to python file for processing and then displays the output from the python file onto the java gui. This is working perfectly on eclipse but when i exported it into a jar file the output is not displayed. I've seen a bunch of other questions like this but they do not give a solution that would help me.

This is how i connect my python script to java.

```
public void connection(String name)
    {
        ProcessBuilder pb= new ProcessBuilder("python","recomold.py","--movie_name",name);
         ///System.out.println("running file");
         Process process = null;
        try {
            process = pb.start();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
         int err = 0;
        try {
            err = process.waitFor();
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        // System.out.println("any errors?"+(err==0 ? "no" : "yes"));
        /* try {
            System.out.println("python output "+ output(process.getInputStream()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }*/
         try {
            matches.setText(output(process.getInputStream()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private String output(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader br = null;
        try{
            br= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String line = null;
            while((line=br.readLine())!=null)
            {
                sb.append(line+"\n");
                //descp.setText("<html><br/><html>");
                //sb.append("\n");
            }
        }
        finally
        {                   
                br.close();                 
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

Comment: Are there any errors in the logs? Any stack traces?

Comment: @rdas no it does not show anything. Any help would be very much appreciated

Comment: The same question has been asked there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56732513/python-output-not-displayed-in-jar-file